# How can I get the mode (Statistic) in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, mode

Basically, in a textbox (txtEl) I'm writing the length of the vector, then add it random numbers (from 1 to 500), showing all of them in a listbox. But I don't know how to get the mode from all those numbers.

```
        Random Aleatorio = new Random();
        int x = Convert.ToInt16(txtEl.Text);

        int[] elementos = new int [x];

        int moda = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < elementos.Length; i++)
        {
            elementos[i] = Aleatorio.Next(1, 500);
            listEl.Items.Add(elementos[i].ToString());



        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this 
Im not real sure what listEl is but you should be able to use it here. If not just add them to a basic list also.

```
var mode = (from item in listEl.Items
                         group item by item into g
                         orderby g.Count() descending
                         select g.Key).First();
```

Comment: listEl is the listbox where I'm adding the random numbers from the vector :)

Comment: yea nevermind its not liking it. But if when you add them to it you also add to standard list then use it there. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, after your `for` loop:

```
var lookup = elementos.ToLookup(n => n);
int maxCount = lookup.Max(g => g.Count());
var modes = lookup.Where(g => g.Count() == maxCount).Select(g => g.Key);
```

Note that there can be multiple modes in your data, so it doesn't really make sense to expect just one `int`, but an enumerable or list of `int`s.

If you want just one mode, you can do `.First()` on the enumerable. If you need to ensure that one mode is selected randomly from the list of modes, do not use `.First()`, but use another random number to select one randomly.